# Partialy ordered set

Tags: order-theory

Can you check if it is a good example of the Hasse diagram for the partialy ordered set with two maximal elements and one minimal element without the least element and with the four elements antichain which is upper bounded but doesn't have supremum?
[image: Hasse diagram]

Comment: Yes, that's ok. Although it's not a minimal example, it has the desired properties.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but again I have to remark that the four element antichain does have a supremum.